# DATA TYPE TIME manupilation

Tags: sql, datetime, aggregate-functions, sqldatatypes

how to aggregate the sells by date i want to know the total of sells for each day

```
|DATE      | SELLS |

|2022-01-27  |48$    |
|2022-01-27  | 25$   |
|2022-01-27  | 150$  |
|2022-01-25  | 55$   |
```

no idea about the query

perhaps i should creat an other table which hold only total sells per day

Answer (score 1):

Do a `GROUP BY`

```
select date, sum(sells)
from tablename
group by date
```

(No need for another table. Such copying of data too often leads to data inconsistency.)

Comment: If you also have a time component you need to get rid off it. e.g. using 
`DATETRUNC(day, date)`

Comment: @tim, it looks like the date column stores dates, not timestamps.